# Quotation Mark-Inception

Tags: command-line, bash, matlab

I have the following variables:

```
file=document.mat
path=~/files
```

Now, I want to call the matlab-function func() (don't worry if you don't know Matlab, it doesn't really matter). The function takes as input argument a file in quotation marks like so:

```
func("/path_to_file/file.extension")
```

or

```
func('/path_to_file/file.extension')
```

However, calling the function from the terminal, I have to set the function itself in double quotation marks:

```
$matlab "func('/path_to_file/file.extension')"
```

(For visibility, omitted some command options such as `-nosplash -r`).

Now, the argument of the function func must be a variable (for reasons), so I want to replace `/path_to_file/file.extension` by `$path/$file`. This is where the problem arises:

```
$matlab "func("$path/$file")"
```

This doesn't work for obvious reasons.

```
$matlab "func('$path/$file')"
```

This doesn't work because single quotation marks suppress variable extension.

```
$matlab "func(`$path/$file`)"
bash:~/files/document.mat: Permission denied
```

What can I do in order to pass variables to the function within ""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following format of quotes:

```
$matlab "func('$path/$file')"
```

Replacing `$matlab` with `echo` (executed on GNU bash, version 4.3.46) result with:

```
$ echo  "func('$path/$file')"
func('/home/username/files/document.mat')
```